# Is there an equivalent of python's __name__ for a Javascript object

Tags: javascript, metaprogramming

How do I find the string form of an object name in javascript?

Answer (score 5):

```
function bar(){};
console.log(bar.name);
```

//Prints 'bar'

This works for functions only, not objects of any other type.

For a CoffeeScript class, you can do this

```
class Foo
f = new Foo
console.log f.constructor.name
#Prints 'Foo'
```

Comment: Consider the `constructor` property of objects. However, this depends on how the function is defined -- `X = function () {}; X.name` results in undefined.

Comment: Thanks, but If I defined a class using Coffeescript, how can I get the name of the class? class.name doesn't work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If a function is defined using `function foo() {…}`, you can get its name using `foo.toString()`. For example:

```
> window.alert.toString()
"function alert() { [native code] }"
```

However, if the function is defined anonymously (ex, `var foo = function() {…}`), then there's no way to get the name `foo`.

**Edit**: it turns out the name can be accessed through `.name` (see Peter Lyons's answer), so using `.toString()` would be silly (although I'll leave my answer here as it may be instructive).

Answer (score 1):

```
function A() {};
var a = new A();
a.constructor.name // => "A"
```